# "it's not the same object as" error when trying to serialize an object

Tags: python, pickle

I've been trying to make a text-based game and figured that I probably need a saving system. This is what I've done so far:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, health, defence, att, inventory, money, name):
        self.health = health
        self.defence = defence
        self.att = att
        self.inventory = inventory
        #set the inventory as a list and add items to it
        self.money = money
    def strike(self, enem):
        ...
    def addtoinv(self, item):
        ...
```

Here's a snippet of my code that makes the Player class.

```
Player = Player(20, 5, 0, [], 0)
```

Here I'm making the player object.

```
f = open("save_file.dat", "wb+")
pickle.dump([Player], f)
```

And here is where the issue occurs. I'm trying to serialize the object and save it to a file but instead it throws this error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Player'>: it's not the same object as __main__.Player
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your class `Player` with the variable `Player`. This is reassigning `Player` to an instance of the class instead of the class itself.

All you need to do is rename your variable to something else

```
p = Player(20, 5, 0, [], 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might have been the class that was the issue, but instead it was the name of the object being the same as the class.